# Scoping Graph Permissions to specific objects

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

does someone know if it's possible to scope Graph Permissions to specific objects?

We know that there are Exchange Online Application Access Policies (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-limit-mailbox-access) but those are only valid for specific scopes like Mail.Read,
Calendars.ReadWrite and so on.

We want to use MS Graph Application Permissions like DeviceManagementConfiguration.ReadWrite.All or Sites.FullControl.All but we can't allow any App access to all objects in the tenant, since there are multiple companies with their own Administrative staff and responsibilites. We already use Administrative Units but those cant use MS Graph Permissions Scopes from what i tried.

Scoping MS Graph Application Permissions to specific objects not possible, no information in documentation from MS.

Answer (score 0):

Graph API permissions are designed to grant broad access to the resources and data within a tenant that falls under the specific category for which the permission is granted. For example, permissions like DeviceManagementConfiguration.ReadWrite.All or Sites.FullControl.All would provide access to all corresponding resources within the tenant

In your scenario, you can build a custom middleware or API layer that sits between your application and Microsoft Graph. This middleware can implement additional authorization logic to restrict access to specific objects or resources based on your business requirements.

You can use groups or any tenant user properties like department to restrict the access in the middleware.

You can also use different applications with restricted assignment under the service principal for the app in Azure AD Enterprise apps to users and groups - [See this guide](https://edi.wang/post/2019/12/13/how-to-allow-only-selected-users-to-access-an-application-in-azure-ad), then implement logic in each app to only access resources for the logical tenant.

You may end up managing two applications for each logical tenant but it will guarantee the separation.

Answer (score 0):

There are some exceptions. For example group owner can manage group by graph api even if he will not have graph group.write permission. In my opinion Microsoft should respect same way permission added by administrative unit in graph.